Why aren't formulas updating when sorting with Google Sheets Python API
I've got a spreadsheet that I'm working with and after a bit of struggle, I got the sortRange request to work. The sheet is sorting, but after the sort, I notice that the references in any formulas are still pointing to the old row rather than to the new row that the entry is now on. Here's my request:
requests = {
        "requests": [
            {
                "sortRange": {
                    "range": {
                        "sheetId": 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                        "startRowIndex": 1,
                        "startColumnIndex": 0
                    },
                    "sortSpecs": [
                        {
                            "dataSourceColumnReference": {
                                "name": "A"
                            },
                            "sortOrder": "ASCENDING"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }

In the sheet I have formulas such as this one:
=IF(ISBLANK('MySheetName'!G29),"",MAX('MySheetName'!G29:29))
If Row 29 gets moved to Row 2, those formulas still reference 29, which makes their calculations very, very off. I'm using the Python API to make this work. Any thoughts?
I'm expecting that any formulas are updated properly with the new row entries. I also tried putting $ in front of the cell references, to no avail.

If you sortmanually using the UI, does the formulas change to G2 from 29?
